# Can Flask post internally in python?

Tags: python, post, flask

Is it possible to make an internal post in flask?  I'm trying to figure out how to post to an external site inside of python. Lets say I have a simple method like:

```
    @app.route("/<test_value>", methods=["GET","POST"])  
        def test_post(test_value):
            ?post?(test_value, url)
            return redirect("/")
```

Is there method I could use to make that post or would I be best off using javascript?

Comment: If you are sending a POST to an endpoint in the same application, a single-threaded server, such as the one used by `app.run()`, will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) library is the most popular one, here is a sample code on how to send a post with some data.

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```